# Capture possible MIME Trees with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a capture group to grab the tree portion of a MIME type. i already know that the input text is a MIME type. As examples:

`MIME Type                               Matched portion`

```
text/plain                           -> No match
application/x-deb                    -> "x"
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml -> "vnd"
application/x.example123             -> "x"
application/prs.vanity               -> "prs"
application/prs-vanity               -> No match
```

Currently, I have `/(?:(prs|vnd|x)\.)|(x-)?`, but I'm trying to consolidate it into a single capture group. Is this possible?

The only other try I've done is `/(?:(prs|vnd|x)[\.-])?`, but that matches, for example, `application/vnd-badly-made` as `vnd` instead of properly not matching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach: match something that's preceded by `application/` and is...

- either `x` symbol followed by `-`,
- or a group of letters followed by `.`

... with this pattern:

```
/(?<=application\/)(?:x(?=-)|[a-z]+(?=\.))/
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fN6yL5). If lookbehind is not an option, use capturing group:

```
/application\/(x(?=-)|[a-z]+(?=\.))/
```

Comment: That looks like it matches `application/x-deb` as `x-`, instead of `x`, though, right?

Comment: @tikiking1 You're right, updated the patterns to reflect that.

Comment: Just for posterity, the `?:` should be removed from the regex.

Comment: Why? It means the non-capturing group; if you use the first pattern, you can safely work with the whole string it covers, without using any capturing group at all.

Comment: The point was to extract the tree. To extract all the parts, I ended up using a look-behind, as `^(application|audio|example|image|message|model|multipart|text|video)/(x(?=[-\.])|(?:prs|vnd)+(?=\.))?(?:(?!x)[-\.])?([^\s]+?)(?:\+(xml|json|ber|der|fastinfoset|wbxml|zip|cbor))?$`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
application/(?:(prs(?!-)|vnd(?!-)|x))(?=\.|-)
```

It matches all your cases.

Comment: This can be rewritten as `\/(?:prs(?!-)|vnd|x(?=[.-]))`, and it'll still match something extra -  like `/vndvndvnd`, for example.

Comment: @raina77ow Good one! Fixed it.  PS: `/` may not always be prefixed by `\\`, like in Java for example (but needed on http://regex101.com though)